# Photoshop: bold is not available for specific font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typesetting

Just starting out with Photoshop and trying to bold my text, but the option is not available. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: I think Bold is not available for that font. You can simply download other variants of it. Simple font search gave me this (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/footlight-mt/). Or you can just add some other effects on it.

Comment: @Dexter I'd upvote that if you'd make it an answer! Please avoid answering questions in the comments--those are made to be deleted later, anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Dexter Your comment is helpful. You must make its answer with some more details, I would like to use it and upvote it.

Comment: Photoshop and all Adobe Software only list installed fonts. If you only see Regular, that's what you have in your computer for that particular font. You can use *Faux Bold* as Ryan suggested below, which is not *true* bold, but something Photoshop constructs around the Regular version.

Comment: @Vincent, It is ok. No problem. As far as my comment helped someone :) Plus Ryan has already answered correctly and gave different solution

Comment: @Dexter Still, please void it in the future. Correct answers in the comments can't be accepted, which hurts site stats and thus credibility. The more Qs that have accepted As, the better we ook for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That font doesn't have a Bold Style available. Photoshop does have "Faux Bold" which is in the Character Panel. It's the first "T" icon.

Here's a much more in-depth Q&A regarding Faux Bold that you should probably read before deciding to use it: [Distinguishing real and faux bold and italics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/distinguishing-real-and-faux-bold-and-italics)

Answer (score 1):

Ryan is correct, your system does not have a bold version of Footlight installed. It is however available as a free download here:

https://ufonts.com/download/footlight-mt-bold/139063.html

Alternately, you can add a stroke to the text layer to bold it up... make sure the text layer is selected, then on the layer palette, under FX at the bottom, select "stroke".

Adjust the stroke settings in the pop-up window until you get the desired thickness you want. Make sure the stroke is set to "outside" or "center". Depending on the typestyle used, somewhere between 1 and 4 px is usually sufficient.